# z-index to stop scrolling header of the page affects other scrolling bars inside the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using z-index to stop scroll the header of the page as below

```
.headerscrolling{
z-index:9005;
}
```

I also use niceScroll Jquery inside center of page which will dynamically create scroll bar based on the div (say id=innerscroll) content using following command.

```
<div id="innerscroll">
```

& Jquery is

```
$("#innerscroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
```

Now the problem is , Nice Scroll bar goes up by the pixel height of header from innerscroll div. Please suggest me what can be done to overcome this issue

**Note**: If i dont Use z-index , its working fine;

**PFB issue in diagrammatic :**
[image]

Comment: i dont think using z-index is the right way to prevent header from scrolling
Few options:
1>When the header is about to go out of view then change its position to Fixed
2>Create another header div with the exact same styling and make its position as Fixed and hide it
When your usual header goes out of view then make the duplicate header visible
This solution worked nice for me

Comment: @Wishy : Thanks, can you give me your working code in answers section ?

Comment: Sure will do so in around 2hours. Sorry about getting back late

Comment: @Wishy : Please get back to me to accept your answer

Comment: extremely sorry i forgot. My code is in another laptop. Will definitely send by today evening.

Comment: logan
Did the below code help you?

Answer (score 1):

Here fixed header menu is the duplicate one that dropdown when scrolled.

Js

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;

    function handleScroll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
        (currentScrollPosition - lastScrollPosition > 0) ? handleScrollDown() : handleScrollUp();   
        lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;
    },0);

}

function handleScrollDown(){

    //if header menu is not in view then no point in checking if it is going out of view
    if(!isheaderMenuTopInView) return;      
    //console.log('inview going out');
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    headerMenuTop = $('#header-menu').offset().top,
    headerMenuBottom = headerMenuTop + $('#header-menu').height();
    if(headerMenuBottom < (windowTop+$('#fixed-header-menu').height())) {
        //console.log('went out of view');
        $('#fixed-header-menu').show(0);
        isheaderMenuTopInView = false;
    }
}

function handleScrollUp(){

    //if header menu is in view then no point in checking if it is coming in view
    if(isheaderMenuTopInView) return;
    //console.log('not in view coming in');
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    headerMenuTop = $('#header-menu').offset().top,
    headerMenuBottom = headerMenuTop + $('#header-menu').height();
    if(headerMenuBottom > (windowTop+$('#fixed-header-menu').height())){
        //console.log('came in view');
        $('#fixed-header-menu').hide(0);
        isheaderMenuTopInView = true;
    }
}
```

Fixed Header menu is the duplicate of header menu

```
<div id = 'headerContainer' class = 'span-12-of-12'>
    <nav>
        <div id = 'fixed-header-menu' class = 'span-12-of-12 menu section group'>                       
            <img class = 'menu-bg' src = './res/MenuBar.png' />
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/home.png' />Home</div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/aboutUs.png' />About Us</div>
            <div class = 'posture-position pp1 menu-item col span-1-of-5'>
                <img class = 'p1' src = './res/posture/p1.png' />
                <img class = 'p2' src = './res/posture/p12.png' />
            </div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/contactUs.png' />Contact Us</div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/gallery.png' />Gallery</div>     
        </div>  
    </nav>

    <div class = 'section group'>                   
        <div class='logo-name  span-3-of-12'>
            <img src = './res/LogoName.png' />
        </div>                  
    </div>  
    <nav>
        <div id = 'header-menu' class = 'menu section group'>                       
            <img class = 'menu-bg' src = './res/MenuBar.png' />
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/home.png' />Home</div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/aboutUs.png' />About Us</div>
            <div class = 'posture-position pp1 menu-item col span-1-of-5'>
                <img class = 'p1' src = './res/posture/p1.png' />
                <img class = 'p2' src = './res/posture/p12.png' />
            </div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/contactUs.png' />Contact Us</div>
            <div class = 'col span-1-of-5 menu-item'><img src = './res/gallery.png' />Gallery</div>     
        </div>  
    </nav>
</div>
```

If you have any doubts kindly get back

Comment: : ) as long as it helps you